# Performance review and detection probability of the CPOD KERNO classifier?

Tags: automated-detection, cpod, classifier

Outside of [Carsten et al., 2019](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/09524622.2018.1477071), are there any good papers that detail the performance and detection probability of the KERNO classifier included in CPOD.exe? I'm aware of multiple papers that compare the classifier to broad-band recordings and open-access classifiers (below), and that certainly gives us insight. However, I have never seen a ROC curve provided by the KERNO authors in a peer-reviewed study.

**References**

Clausen K.T., Tougaard J., Carstensen J., Delefosse M., Teilmann J. (2019) Noise affects porpoise click detections – the magnitude of the effect depends on logger type and detection filter settings. Bioacoustics 28(5): 443-458.

Sarnocinska, J., Tougaard, J., Johnson, M., Madsen, P. T., & Wahlberg, M. (2016, July). Comparing the performance of C-PODs and SoundTrap/PAMGUARD in detecting the acoustic activity of harbor porpoises (Phocoena phocoena). In Proceedings of Meetings on Acoustics 4ENAL (Vol. 27, No. 1, p. 070013). Acoustical Society of America.

Jacobson, E. K., Merkens, K. P., Forney, K. A., & Barlow, J. (2017). Comparison of harbor porpoise (Phocoena phocoena) echolocation clicks recorded simultaneously on two passive acoustic monitoring instruments. NOAA-TM-NMFS-SWFSC-583; http://doi.org/10.7289/V5/TM-SWFSC-583

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would not be an easy study partly because the CPOD uses a proprietary analysis algorithm.

First a CPOD does not record raw acoustic data, but runs an onboard detection algorithm which detects transient sounds at a very high false positive rate and saves some basic metrics such as time, amplitude, frequency etc. for each detection. The saved detections are then run through a click train detection algorithm to remove false positives and determine species. It is difficult (but not impossible) for a manual analyst to verify porpoise events in the "raw" CPOD detection data, however, the detection threshold is also quite high (see Clausen 2019) and so some lower amplitude but audible detections will be missed. Therefore, a SoundTrap or other recorder should probably be used to determine "truth", however, this is technically difficult as both CPOD and SoundTrap clocks drift plus ground truthing SoundTrap data is currently very time consuming. Inevitably, any study like this, unless very well resourced, will have a low sample size and the manufacturer could dismiss negative results on those grounds.

Another or additional potential option is to test the CPOD click train detection algorithm using simulations. Take a large number of real porpoise click trains (e.g. detected on SoundTraps) and run them through the CPOD click train detector at different signal to noise ratio's to try and characterise how the algorithm performs. Unfortunately, this is not straightforward because the click train detection algorithm is not open source and there is no public API to call it in code. The only way to do this is therefore to create "fake" CPOD detection files and run these through the CPOD click train program. (We had some success with and happy to share code but we never took it further than a proof of concept)

It should also be noted that, as far as I am aware, there is very little room to tweak the click train algorithm - click trains detected by CPODs are graded as low, medium, high probability and so an ROC curve would only have three points. Also note most of this also applies to the new FPOD.

Answer (score 3):

The SAMBAH project in the Baltic processed 400 years of C-POD data and the detection performance - the effective detection radius - was estimated using more than one method to give a population estimate of porpoises.
Data was collected over parts of 2 years from 300 sites and 60% of these sites, in a very coherent spatial pattern, had zero detections despite logging porpiose like clicks (because the clicks were not in trains).

The KERNO-F classifier for the F-POD does have sensitivity controls that the user can tweak (not recommended) but, as the author of it, I would not use them to contruct ROC curves because ROC curves are specific to noise regimes as well as instruments, and sampling a sufficient spread of noise regimes to produce a generalised value would be a vast project giving a result that might not fit any specific location!

The classifier is long and I would not dream of assessing it by unpacking it.  It's only possible to develop and optimise such algorithms empirically, and that is essentially what neural networks and most machine leraning does.
In this case the classifier has been emprically tuned to work in a wide range of adverse environments, so that most users will get data that, after validation of a sample of detections, can be used without editing.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge. I have explicitly asked the creator of this software while at a conference workshop about this, and they answered me like a politician. I think that they have zero interest in producing an ROC curve while their sales are hot. Would be keen to hear if there have been efforts to do so, perhaps in the grey literature.